# What is the minimal requirement for a Fourier transformation?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have a lot of comprehension questions that I can't really figure out by googling:

1. The difference between a Fourier transformation and a Fourier series. Am I correct in thinking that the difference: transforms are for continous cases and series are for discrete cases ?
2. What functions can be Fourier transformed? Which not? I read/learned once that piecewise continuity is enough for a function to be transformed as long as it can be extended to 2 - pi periodic continuity (so the pieces can be "stringed together to a periodic wave")

Is this correct?

Comment: 1. is more or less correct but 2. not so much. To be fourier transformed a function has to have some integrability properties because the fourier transform is defined as an integral over all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. i'm not looking for complicated counter examples and such, just the most generally applicable case , as in, what is the "weakest" function, that is still transformable

Comment: We can readily talk about the fourier transform of $L^1$ functions because $\|e^{2\pi i x \xi}\|\leq 1$ and we can use a density argument to extend to $L^2$. Beyond that we can go to distributions and say something about Schwartz functions but I don't really know what is the "weakest' function for this.

Comment: So all L1 and L2 functions are fourier transformable?

Comment: Yes. The proof is not so bad, you first develop the theory in $L^1$, then look at functions in $L^1\cap L^2$, and use a density argument to extend this to $L^2$ itself.

Comment: By similar density arguments, all $L^p$ functions are transformable and the Fourier transform extends to a isometric operator from $L^p$ to $L^q$ where $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 q = 1$. In fact, the minimum requirement to reasonably define a Fourier transform is much less stringent: the function must lie in the space of tempered distributions.

Comment: wish you guys would just answer so i could mark your answer as correct lol , but thanks for your great answers anyhow

Comment: It's good for people to write answers; that way the site answer rate is more accurate. I suggest that @shakshoka1234 post an answer, and mark their own answer if nobody else will post their response as an answer.